# Maximum Entropy Distribution with Reciprocal Symmetry

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, entropy

What is the maximum entropy distribution $F$ on $(0,\infty)$ with mean $1$ and  $\Pr(x\le a)= \Pr(x\ge\frac{1}{a})$ for all $a$?

After taking a derivative we find that the pdf $F'=f$ must satisfy $af(a)=\frac{1}{a}f(\frac{1}{a})$.

I tried using calculus of variations with lagrange multipliers, but the integrals look like they cannot be dealt with analytically.

Alternatively I would also be happy simply having a pdf with mean $1$ and the given symmetry, which is not necessarily of maximum entropy. I looked at the [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) which has the symmetry but not the mean.

One Ansatz that almost worked out is $f(x) = c\frac{1}{x} e^{-a(x+\frac{1}{x})}$. But here $\int f\,\mathrm dx =2cK_0(2a) \overset{!}{=}1 $ and $\int x f \,\mathrm dx = 2 cK_1(2a) \overset{!}{=}1 $ leads to $K_0(x) = K_1(x)$. But the only point where those two modified Bessel functions of the second kind agree is at $x=\infty$, which leads to $f(x)=\delta(x-1)$, i.e. a dirac impulse at $x=1$. This is indeed a solution; albeit a useless one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\def\deq{\stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=}}\def\aseq{\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}{=}}$For any postive $X$ satisfying $P(X \leqslant a) = P\left( X \geqslant \dfrac{1}{a} \right)$ for any $a > 0$, since$$
P\left( \frac{1}{X} \leqslant a \right) = P\left( X \geqslant \dfrac{1}{a} \right) = P(X \leqslant a), \quad \forall a > 0
$$
then $\dfrac{1}{X} \deq X$ and$$
E(X) = \frac{1}{2} (E(X) + E(X)) = \frac{1}{2} \left( E(X) + E\left( \frac{1}{X} \right) \right) = \frac{1}{2} E\left( X + \frac{1}{X} \right) \geqslant 1,
$$
where the equality holds iff $X \aseq 1$. Thus the only distrbution satisfies the symmetry condition with mean $1$ is $δ(x - 1)$, which renders the whole problem degenerate.

Comment: For getting the last inequality you applied Jensen?

Comment: @leonbloy No, simply AM-GM: $X+\dfrac1X\geqslant2$.